# Jquery XML parsing

Tags: jquery

I have this XML

```
<items>
  <item validate="NotEmpty ValidEmail" class="xxx yyy zzz" type="input" name="Id" value="" label="Id" />
  <item validate="NotEmpty" type="input" name="NazovProjektu" value="" label="NazovProjektu" />
  <item type="input" name="Oz" value="" label="Oz" />
```

I want to get the value of the attribute `name` of each element with attribute `class` containing string `yyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, haven't tested it yet. Assuming the XML is already parsed and inside an object named `xml`.

```
$(xml).find("[class~='yyy']").each(function(i, element) {
    console.log($(element).attr("name"));
});
```

Comment: @user updated with correct example. the previous one clearly wrong, it was searching in the element text, rather than attributes.

Answer (score 1):

A [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) will get you the elements.  The [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function will get you the name of the element.  Using [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on the jQuery Object will allow you to iterate through the element in the jQuery Object.

```
var yourXML = "...";
$("[class*='zzz']", yourXML).each(function() {
   alert($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

Comment: but zzz is the value of the attribute class and the XML is in a javascript value.

Comment: A class selector shouldn't work against XML. Generic XML doesn't have classes; an attribute just being named `class` does nothing special. Note that in jQuery this may still work by coincidence if it falls back to the JavaScript Sizzle selector engine (instead of browser native selectors), since this doesn't know that an XML `class` is any different from an HTML one. But this is not really behaviour to be relied on. An explicit `class` attribute selector is more reliable.

Comment: @user137348: if you mean you have XML in a string, the best thing to do is not have XML in a string, because there isn't a standard way of parsing it. You can cover many but not all browsers with branched code for `new DOMParser` and `new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLDOM')`, but it's a pain. Getting an already-parsed XML DOM from an XMLHttpRequest (`ajax()` etc) is easier and better-supported.

Comment: thak you for the explanation. Its in a XMLHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 1):

try following, it should help you out.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml)
        {
          //find every yyy classname and alert its name
          $(xml).find(".yyy").each(function()
          {
            alert($(this).attr('name'));
          });
        }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do something like

```
$("item[class*=yyy]", xml).each(function() { 
    $(this).attr('name'); 
});
```

Comment: `~=` for HTML-style space-separated classes. `*=` would match a class `ayyyb`.